# Refer to Term ID from $content field

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm attempting to get the taxonomy term id from a field in the node template for a content type. I'm currently rendering the names of the terms using this

```
render($content['field_tags'][value]);
```

This works fine for grabbing the names of the terms. However I would like to be able to grab the actual term ids from those fields instead of just the names. Using devel I do see that that information exists, however I'm not sure how to refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the Answer:You can use [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7). in your theme template.php

```
function YourTheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['tags_tids'] = array();
  foreach ($$variables['field_tags'] as $key => $tag) {
    $variables['tags_tids'] = $tag['tid'];
  }
}
```

then in your node.tpl you could loop through the "$tags_tids"array, and do whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I already tried that. When I do that all it spits out is 'Array'

Comment: not so bad, try to loop through array using foreach

Comment: Printing out the items of the foreach loop gives me: '1',

'markup',

'Array',

'Array',

'TagName', but no term id.

Comment: Just updated the answer with different way to get the tids. give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Simply double click the value you called in Devel and you will be offered the concrete path to your value. It then may be displayed like `$content->field_tags[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid']`